# how to ensure that a particular token is always added by the user in the input file?

Tags: regex, yacc

input file:
    parameter1  abc
    parameter2  123
    parameter3  xyz
if parameter2 is mandatory to be defined and the user forgets to do so,can yacc be used to report about this missing variable?

Comment: In general, yes, you can use a parser (generated by yacc) combined with a lexical analyzer (generated by a tool like lex) to validate your input file.  But whether the tools are a good fit depends on the variability of your input file.  Is the file always a maximum of 3 lines, each headed by "parameterN"?  Then a simpler solution, one using your preferred programming language's string-manipulation tools, and not using a yacc-generated parser, might be a better choice for you.

Comment: the file can have any number of lines. there can be 100 such lines.what i have mentioned here is just an example.there can be various parameters with different names and values.

Comment: So these are named parameters, which suggests to me that order is *not* significant.  In which case, yacc is a bad fit for your needs.  Think about a tool like grep.

Answer (score 1):

I will expand on my comment and try to make a proper answer.  yacc is a tool for doing syntactic analysis, that is, the analysis of the grammatical arrangement of words or tokens.  Use a yacc-generated parser to recognize as valid a string of tokens like

```
a = b + 2
```

and to reject as invalid a string like

```
2 b a = +
```

The same tokens are present, but in a different, nongrammatical order.

Instead, a simple string-matching tool like grep that uses some simple regular expressions seems to be the choice for you.  The regular expression

```
/^parameter2/
```

matches any line that starts with the string "parameter2", and the regular expression

```
/^parameter[0-9]\s*[0-9]+$/
```

matches any line that consists of a parameter numbered from 0 to 9, some whitespace, and a string of digits.  You have other options for matching across lines, matching case insensitively, and so on.

---

Now, if your particular problem includes validating type information for the values assigned to the parameters, e.g., `parameter2` must take an integer, not a string, yacc might be useful.  But, as I've written, I think it's a lot of apparatus to set up for what reads like a simple problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a syntactic rule that says `parameter2` must appear exactly once in the input:

```
valid_file: opt_param_list param2 opt_param_list
    ;
```

The grammar would then only recognize as syntactically valid a file that contained a `param2` somewhere.

However, what you're after is more of a semantic check than a syntactic check; you'd probably do better implementing the rule in the actions rather than in the grammar:

```
valid_file: opt_param_list
    {   if (param2_specified())
            YYACCEPT;
        else
        {
            err_report("No specification for parameter2");
            YYABORT;
        }
    }
    ;
```